# HttpClient send Authorization bearer empty

Tags: c#, httpclient, webapi

In Startup  class, I use AddHttpClient method that aquire a jwt token (using MSAL) and assign it to DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", response.AccessToken);
```

I've used the accessToken with Postman and it is valid when I use it later in may code.

In the code where I call the API, I resolve a HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("client");
```

[image: HttpClient details]

and try to call my API. The call fails with 401 and looking to HttpRequestMessage, I see that Authorization Header exist but parameter is empty:

[image: RequestMessage details]

If I construct a second HttpClient and assign Authorization header from the one constructed with IHttpClientFactory, the call work like a charm:

```
var httpClient2 = new HttpClient();
httpClient2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization;

// This call fails
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("Game/All", cancellationToken);
// This call succeed
response = await httpClient2.GetAsync("Game/All", cancellationToken);
```

What is wrong in my code? The HttpClient provided by IHttpClientFactory had not obviously the same behavior, but why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code where you "aquire a jwt token and assign it to DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization."

Comment: Does it work if you add a generic header that is "Authorization" instead of using the `.Authorization` property?

Comment: @Crowcoder Same behavior, the token is recognized ad an Authorization header. The call fails with the first httpClient and succeed with the header extracted from the first one... it is insane

Comment: The pictures show the different story then you tell. The first client is ok, but the second is empy Can you post the startup pls?

Comment: @Serge No, the first picture show the DefaultRequestHeader of the first HttpClient and the second picture is the HttpRequestMessage details of the response of the call done with the same HttpClient.
The call with the second HttpClient succeed and the Authorization header in HttpRequestMessage is correctly filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, it was due to my-me-from-past.

Later in my code, I've registered the same `HttpClient` (same name) with a `HttpMessageHandler` that was in charge to fill the Authorization header before each call with the token.

Since the work was not finished, the handler fill the header with an empty string.

The two `HttpClient` configuration was executed and that was the last one who get the last word...